# Загрузка изображения по частям в Python через GDAL

Tags: python, изображения

Мне необходимо открыть изображение в формате `*.tif` для последующей обработки в GDAL. Я использую стандартный код:

```
data = gdal.Open("a.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
img = data.ReadAsArray()
```

Все работает хорошо на изображениях размера порядка нескольких мегабайт. При загрузке изображения порядка 1Гб начинает сильно расходоваться память (примерно 10Гб).
Есть ли способы загрузить только часть изображения для последовательной обработки?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @logan-byers за [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42509430/1980214)

В функции `ReadAsArray()` есть параметры: `ReadAsArray(x_off, y_off, x_size, y_size)`